# Can't understand MPI_Bcast

Tags: c++, c, mpi, mpich

I writed simple MPI programm using MPI_Bcast function, but I can't understand why my programm doesn't finish.

**Here's code**

```
#include "mpi.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int ProcNum, ProcRank, RecvRank;
    MPI_Status Status;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &ProcNum);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &ProcRank);

    RecvRank = ProcRank;
    MPI_Bcast(&RecvRank, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Recv(&RecvRank, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &Status);

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code has a deadlock. After your `MPI_Bcast`, you have an `MPI_Recv` with no matching `MPI_Send`, which causes your code to hang. I assume from the way you've asked your question that you think you need an `MPI_Recv` to receive information sent via `MPI_Bcast`, but that is not correct. The `MPI_Bcast` command by itself (without the `MPI_Recv` afterwards) will achieve what you want.